# Как определить, является ли бинарное дерево деревом поиска?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Предложите алгоритм, который определяет, является ли дерево бинарным деревом поиска? Оцените временную сложность.

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/3042

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, как считаете, ошибку (static struct node \*prev = NULL;) в программе №4, которая делает ее "одноразовой" все заметили, но решили это не обсуждать ?

Comment: Реквестирую тег «домашнее задание» *желтая рожа.жпг*

Comment: Зачем надо было конкурсный вопрос минусовать ?

Comment: А кто-то еще и тревогу нажал, тревожный наш.

Comment: @Типичный программист, можете объяснить почему Вы предпочли принять ответ @Ник, а не @cf_anonymous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получился такой алгоритм:

```
bool isSearchTree(BinaryTree * tree) {
    if (tree == NULL)
        return false;
    if (tree->root == NULL)
        return true;

    return _isSearchTree(tree->root);
}
bool _isSearchTree(BinaryTreeNode * node) {
    BinaryTreeNode * pnode = node->parent;
    BinaryTreeNode * tnode = node;

    while(pnode != NULL) {
        if (pnode->leftChild == tnode){
            if (pnode->value < node->value)
                return false;
        } else {
            if (pnode->value > node->value)
                return false;
         }

        tnode = pnode;
        pnode = pnode->parent;
    }

    bool isLeft, isRight;
    if (node->leftChild != NULL)
        isLeft = _isSearchTree(node->leftChild);
    else 
        isLeft = true;
    if (node->rightChild != NULL)
        isRight = _isSearchTree(node->rightChild);
    else
        isRight = true;

    return isLeft && isRight;
}
```

Comment: А время-то какое? Похоже на O(NlogN) в среднем... (скорее всего ошибаюсь)

Comment: @Ник, у Вас в node еще и указатель наверх (parent) появился ? 

Чем вам код из Geeks не понравился ? IMHO лучше не придумать.

Answer (score 3):

Немного псевдокода, который чудесным образом напоминает C++

```
struct node{
   node *l,*r;
   int key;
};

bool isSearchTree(node *p, int minKey, int maxKey){
   if (p == nullptr)
      return true;
   if (minKey < p->key && p->key < maxKey)
      return isSearchTree(p->l, minKey, p->key) && isSearchTree(p->r, p->key, maxKey);
   return false;
}
const int minInt = (1<<30)*2;
const int maxInt = minInt - 1;
bool isSearchTree(node *root){
   return isSearchTree(root, minInt, maxInt); //можно без бесконечностей,
                                              //но это захламляет идею
}
```

Comment: @cf_anonymous, неправильно. 

См. мой комментарий к ответу @jonyrock.

Comment: Проэмулируйте руками код на том примере и поймите, что правильно, в отличие от кода @jonyrock выше. Заметьте, что функция точно эмулирует процедуру добавления элемента в бинарное дерево, передавая по рекурсии отрезок возможных значений ключа, которые попали в поддерево. При проверке элемента с ключом 11 будет вызов isSearchTree(..., 5, 10) и ответ false.

P.S. Сложность худшего случая, очевидно, O(число элементов в дереве), среднего - зависит от понимания среднего.

Comment: @cf_anonymous, согласен, хороший алгоритм, плюсую. 

"Без бесконечностей захламляет код" - это Вы имеете в виду передавать уровень и для уровня 0 - не проверять  ?

Answer (score 0):

Алгоритм (псевдокод):

```
   bool isSearchTree(Tree tree) {

        bool isLeftOk = true;
        bool isRightOk = true;
        if (tree.left != null) { 
            isLeftOk = tree.left.root <= tree.root);
            if(isLeftOk) isLeftOk = isSearchTree(tree.left);
        }
        if (tree.right != null) { 
            isRightOk = tree.right.root > tree.root);
            if(isRightOk) isRightOk = isSearchTree(tree.right);
        }

        return isLeftOk && isRightOk;
    }
```

Осталось только определить класс Tree

Временная сложность: O(n) где n - кол-во вершин.

Док-во: в алгоритме просматривается каждая вершина не более 3-х раз.

Comment: Можно еще оптимизировать, прекращая проверки, как только любой из isLeftOk, isRightOk станет `false`.

Comment: Если я все верно понял, то есть ошибка. Вы не смотрите зависимость конкретной вершины ко всему дереву.

Comment: См. первый абзац на http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/3042

Comment: Согласен с @Ник и @Котик. В своем первом комментарии не заметил ошибки.

Очевидно правильный алгоритм это METHOD 4(Using In-Order Traversal) из [http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/3042](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/3042)

Comment: Формальное док-во корректности. 
Если дерево BST - то очевидно функция вернет true. Просто по определению BST.
Если не BST, тогда есть какая-то вершина, у которой не выполнено основной свойство BST. Функция просматривает все вершины если BST. Но если функция не просмотрела какую-то вершину, то это значит что основное свойство не выполнено у родителя. Значит дерево точно не BST.

Приведенный выше алгоритм работает за O(n^2). Надеюсь понятно почему?

Comment: Выше в смысле от товарища @Ник вариант

Comment: @jonyrock, посмотрите на дерево

            10
        5        20
    3       11

Что скажете про (11) в *левом* поддереве от корня ?

Answer (score -1):

Бинарное дерево поиска это и есть нелинейная структура для хранения множества элементов. Так же и любая списковая структура, дерево должно допускать **вставка, удаление и поиск элементов**. Для поискового дерева требуется операция вставки, которая правильно располагает новый элемент. ну как то, так.

Answer (score -1):

Для начала, все данные в таком дереве имеет определённый линейный порядок(теги, указатели, файлы и т.д.). В бинарном дереве поиска каждой вершине присваивают значение, которое называют ключом. Ключ - это элемент некоторого линейно упорядоченного множества: два различных элемента этого множества можно сравнить.

Answer (score -1):

Если в левом поддереве содержаться элементы с ключом< ключа узла и в правом поддереве содержатся элементы с ключом>ключа узла то это и есть бинарное дерево поиска

Answer (score -1):

Для каждой вершины, которая не является листом, левый сын должен быть меньше, а правый больше.

Comment: И откуда вы все понаехали-то? :)

Comment: @cyber1 Не сын, а поддерево. Т.е. каждый из потомков в левом поддереве должен быть меньше узла, в в правом, соответственно, каждый из потомков должен быть больше узла.

Answer (score -2):

Я бы сделал следующим способом:

1. Разделю дерево на 2 поддерева.
2. В цикле прошелся бы по левому поддереву произвольного узла А и проверил следующее: во всех узлах значение ключа < значение ключа узла А ? continue : raise "Дерево на поисковое"
3. В цикле прошелся бы по правому поддереву произвольного узла А и проверил следующее: во всех узлах значение ключа >= значение ключа узла А ? raise "дерево поисковое!" : raise "Дерево на поисковое"

Временную сложность оценил бы как высокую где-то O(log2n)

Comment: Цыкл для *произвольного узла А*. Браво.